# Texture Painting duplicating

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-painting, mirror, duplicate

I am quite new to blender and I have been experiencing some problems with texture painting.  I am currently working on fixing textures of a mesh scanned using a lidar.  It is complicated as there are so many textures, the UV map is a lot to handle.  The room contains different objects and therefore, I work on objects individually, one object at a time i.e., door, sink etc where I bring the texture pieces together.  I managed to get fix some of the elements, however, when I try to use texture paint on the object I am working, the paints is applied to the other parts of the room even though the only item I have selected is sink and I am using the mask as well.  Similarly, upon using fill paint it as there would be no brush strokes but the same paint strokes appeared in the room.  I also tried recalculating the normal, and checking the asymmetry aspects but I am still struggling with the same problem.

If anyone could give me some advice, I would appreciate it. It would also be great if someone can point to me in the right direction.

Comment: Try painting on the texture instead of the model.

Comment: Do you intend to keep any of the original texture from the scan?

Comment: @TheLabCat, hey thanks for the reply.  The method I followed was; texture paint > draw, mix(or add), to make modification to the texture which paints over the existing one.  So, yes, I believe I painted over the texture. However, if this is something different, please let me know as I am new here to using Blender.  To answer your second question, I do need to keep the original texture as the final design needs to look very similar to the original design of the room. But open to trying out your suggestions if any. Thanks for your time

Comment: As in, paint in the image editor instead of the 3D viewport editor. Did you try that?